# Find source of Google Fonts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-fonts

I have some Google Fonts loading that I have spent the past 2 hours trying to track down the source of. Some Google Fonts are being loaded purposefully, but others are being loaded from god knows where. I have searched my text and database for the references, but I just cannot find them anywhere.

Plugins to dequeue all Google Fonts aren't workable because I am purposefully loading a small number of the total fonts loading. I've deleted all themes I'm not using, and removed all plugins

These extra fonts make up a third of my page's total size and over half the requests and any ideas on how to track down the source or dequeue them individually would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google Fonts are often loaded by your theme. There are numerous places where these can be loaded from including functions.php, header.php, from within a CSS stylesheet (@import), etc.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I've checked all of those and many more places, then did a full text search of every file in my installation and of the database itself. No traditional search method so far has elucidated the origin.

Comment: Do you mind sharing what theme you are using?

Comment: Sure I'm using Astra. It should load Source Sans Pro, as currently configured. I am also using Elementor, but I have disabled (in theory) font loading by Elementor. Those are the only places I can logically think fonts would be loading from, but still extra fonts load.

Comment: I know its an obvious suggestion but have you inspected the outputted Source Code? Maybe there will be a clue or two, within said code?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in a comment above you are using Astra WordPress theme. Have you checked `inc/customizer/class-astra-font-families.php` file? This is the file they used for loading various Google fonts.

Furthermore, if you know for which element the theme is loading certain fonts you can remove the code by inspecting. All the font-family css are in `assets/css/minified/style.min.css` file.

And please mention for which section/area you are seeing those Google fonts.